# Blackberry 10 ListView - multiselect

Tags: blackberry-10

I am in need of a bit of help regarding cascades ListView, I found some code a few weeks ago from this great site and have used it to show a tiled ListView in an application.

I have tried to go one step further now and have multiselect in the context menu - this is working ok apart from one issue which is when I select more in the context menu after pressing on a ListItem for a couple of seconds the highlighted ListItem doesn't remain highlighted any longer. So then the user will think they have to press it again to highlight it.

```
void CustomImageView::select(bool b) {

qDebug() << "select isselected=" << b;
if (b)
{
    mHighlightContainer->setOpacity(0.9f);

}
else
{
    mHighlightContainer->setOpacity(0.0f);
}

}
void CustomImageView::reset(bool selected, bool activated)
{
Q_UNUSED(activated);
qDebug() << "reset";
select(selected);
}

void CustomImageView::activate(bool activate)
{
qDebug() << "activate  ";
select(activate);
}
```

Here is the output when I press select more in the menu (at which point the listitem is highlighted as required)

activate
select isselected= true
activate
select isselected= false

If I comment out select(activate); from activate function then the multiselect seems to work as required (it will highlight the item i long press) and stay highlighted but then when i just press (not long press) an item in the list it won't highlight any longer so there is no feedback for the user when tapping an item - it seems i can't have both!

Anybody know what I can do to solve this please?